# Making System.setProperty platform independent in a Maven Project for Selenium Tests

Tags: java, maven, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently creating selenium automation using webdriver in Maven using Java. 
Now for initializing the browsers such as Chrome and IE I have to set  the system property such as

`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\somewhereintheworkingdir\\drivers\chromedriver.exe");`

Now, my deliverable is in terms of JAR. I am using maven so this is currently under main>resources>drivers>chromedriver.exe

So after package it will be unders root>drivers>chromedriver.exe

So How to make the system property that it will run in both the cases?

I researched about some constants like `java.class.path` or `java.file.seperator` etc. but I am not sure how they will useful here in this case.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: The executable is not going to be able to run inside the jar. You will have to unpack it from the jar into the file system and then set the property to that location.

Comment: Hi Maba. You rock. Okay so you mean to say that if I have a exe file in a jar it will not run?. I think if this is the case then I can solve the issue as the defult location is the project root directory.

Comment: You'll either have to unpack the exe file **or** deliver it aside the jar.

Comment: I think I can not unpack the exe file as it is a driver of chrome to run for selenium tests. You mean to say maven package will not have this file inside the jar itself? it is also fine then.

Comment: I did a small POC, the jar file does contain the exe file after maven package. so I can give jar file as a deliverable and then they can import it as a project

Comment: It will be packaged inside the jar but it is not going to be useful until someone unpacks it. The executable must be available in the file system when being used.

Comment: If you read this [Information about the Chrome Driver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver) you'll see that the `webdriver.chrome.driver` will have to point to a location in the file system where the `chromedriver.exe` is. As I have said it is not going to work when it is bundled inside the jar, it has to be unpacked to a physical directory in the file system.

Comment: If you are using Maven, you may also want to look at this:  https://github.com/Ardesco/selenium-standalone-server-plugin  It is a maven plugin that will download the standalone executables for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest having a look at this:

https://github.com/Ardesco/Selenium-Maven-Template

The relevant parts are the POM where it uses this plugin:

```
<properties>
    <standalone.binary.root.folder>${project.basedir}/selenium_standalone_binaries</standalone.binary.root.folder>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>selenium-tests</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.lazerycode.selenium</groupId>
                    <artifactId>driver-binary-downloader-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.9.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <rootStandaloneServerDirectory>${standalone.binary.root.folder}</rootStandaloneServerDirectory>
                        <downloadedZipFileDirectory>${project.basedir}/selenium_standalone_zips</downloadedZipFileDirectory>
                        <customRepositoryMap>${project.basedir}/RepositoryMap.xml</customRepositoryMap>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>selenium</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

and in the base class where it pulls in the locations of the binaries:

```
private static ResourceBundle _prop = ResourceBundle.getBundle("dev");
//Load standalone executable if required
switch (browserType) {
    case CHROME:
        if (System.getProperties().getProperty("os.arch").toLowerCase().equals("x86_64") || System.getProperties().getProperty("os.arch").toLowerCase().equals("amd64")) {
            if (System.getProperties().getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("windows")) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", _prop.getString("binaryRootFolder") + "/windows/googlechrome/64bit/26/chromedriver.exe");
            } else if (System.getProperties().getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("mac")) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", _prop.getString("binaryRootFolder") + "/osx/googlechrome/64bit/26/chromedriver");
            } else if (System.getProperties().getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("linux")) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", _prop.getString("binaryRootFolder") + "/linux/googlechrome/64bit/26/chromedriver");
            }
        } else {
            if (System.getProperties().getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("windows")) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", _prop.getString("binaryRootFolder") + "/windows/googlechrome/32bit/26/chromedriver.exe");
            } else if (System.getProperties().getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("mac")) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", _prop.getString("binaryRootFolder") + "/osx/googlechrome/32bit/26/chromedriver");
            } else if (System.getProperties().getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("linux")) {
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", _prop.getString("binaryRootFolder") + "/linux/googlechrome/32bit/26/chromedriver");
            }
        }
        break;
    case IE:
        if (System.getProperties().getProperty("os.arch").toLowerCase().equals("x86_64") || System.getProperties().getProperty("os.arch").toLowerCase().equals("amd64")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", _prop.getString("binaryRootFolder") + "/windows/internetexplorer/64bit/2.29.0/IEDriverServer.exe");
        } else {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", _prop.getString("binaryRootFolder") + "/windows/internetexplorer/32bit/2.29.0/IEDriverServer.exe");
        }
        break;
}
```

You also need to have a properties file in src/main/resources (has to be in main, not test) that maven can update at build time to pass in properties set in the POM/overridden on the command line.

That file would look like this:

```
binaryRootFolder=${standalone.binary.root.folder}
```

The easiest thing to do would be clone the project linked to at the start of this answer and just run:

```
mvn verify -Pselenium-tests
```

That will show you everything working and give you a good base to start from.